# How to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when changing parent value from within a child?

Tags: angular

In our application, the router-outlet is place within a togglable sidebar inside the `app.component`. The visibility of the sidebar is managed by the `SideBarService`. The button used for toggling the sidebar uses an `*ngIf` to show either a show or hide arrow.

```
<div id="sidebar" [style.width.px]="this.sideBarService.getWidth()">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <a id="sidebar-toggle-button" (click)="toggleSideBar()">
        <div *ngIf="this.sideBarService.hidden; then inactive else active"></div>
        <ng-template #active><i class="material-icons ui-icon-chevron-left"></i></ng-template>
        <ng-template #inactive><i class="material-icons ui-icon-chevron-right"></i></ng-template>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SideBarService{
    public width: number;
    public hidden;

    public changeWidth(width: number): void {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public getWidth(): number {
        return (this.hidden === true ? 0 : this.width);
    }

    public hide(): void {
        this.hidden = true;
    }

    public show(): void {    
        this.hidden = false;
    }
}
```

Now, the place where the `sideBarService.hidden` value is being changed is from components shown in the router-outlet. Maybe that is the reason why I'm constantly getting the following error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'. Current
>   value: 'ngIf: false'.

I believe it is because the change is triggered from a child component of the app-component. But I do not understand how I should solve this issue.

Comment: instead of directly calling the service variable from template call it through the component

Comment: You mean binding a local variable inside app.component to the the service.hidden variable and check the local variable in `*ngIf`?

Comment: You could move your `hide` call into a `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` so that it runs on the next tick?

Comment: @AlexPeters: This is exactly how I solved it as a workaround, but it feels to me like using `setTimeout` isn't a proper solution. Or is it the only way in my case?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  I just remember reading in the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) about this being a viable solution in some instances.

Comment: try to test ```constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){}```  and after hide call  ```this.cdr.detectChanges``` .

Comment: @fatemefazli: This did indeed help! Thank you!

Comment: you'r welcome, so i will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use angular [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) that Checks view and its children. Use in combination with detach to implement local change detection checks.

```
import { Component , ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

and after hide call:

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```